# Disable the alarm on a 2001 Audi A6

Tags: audi, electronics, alarm

I want to disable the alarm on a 2001 Audi A6 because its goes off arbitrarily, a lot. I want to disable the entire alarm. not just the internal movement sensor, How can I do this?

Comment: Not sure on an A6, but on my Jetta, the controller was also responsible for the central locks, and anything the key-fob remote does.  Are you OK to lose all that functionality?

Comment: The next option would be to find out _why_ it's going off.  There are door sensors, a hood sensor, and a trunk sensor.  My Jetta also had an internal switch inside the stereo head unit., just in case you got past everything else and really wanted a proprietary HU.  The hood sensor is the one that most frequently has issues since its not sealed safely inside the dry car.  You could also unplug the alarm horn - it's not always the same as the beep-beep horn.

Comment: I think the alarm horn is different than the beep-beep horn. And finding that would solve the noise problem, though the lights would still flash (potentially draining the battery?). I'll try to find the hood sensor. Thanks again.

Comment: It's winter now and the problem does not occur. Said conversely, the problem occurs in hot weather. Could that be a hint as to which sensor is the problem?

Comment: Materials do expand with heat and contract or stiffen with the cold.  That said, the whole car is subjected to hot or cold, so I don't think that helps narrow it down.  It could mean that a switch is just a _leeetle_ bit out of adjustment.  Of course it also means that since you can't reproduce the problem, you can't troubleshoot any further.